# Synchronous Requests to Ember Mirage

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I'm having a frustrating time, and I'm not sure if it's Ember Mirage causing the problem or not.
I have the following code in a service.

```
    Ember.$.get({
        url: `/api/online-courses/${Ember.get(course, 'id')}/courseData`,
        async: false, // use of deferreds, or promises, is deprecated with this setting
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', Ember.get(service, 'ajax.headers')['Authorization'])
        },
        success: (result) => {
          globalState.initialized = true
          Ember.get(service, 'store').pushPayload('course-datum', result)
          initializeValues()
          returnVal = 'true'
        },
        error: (args) => {
          returnVal = 'false'
        }
      })

      return returnVal
```

I also have the route declared in my `mirage/config.js` file.  It is set up to only use mirage during unit tests.

During the tests, I can follow the code execution through the XHR request, into the Mirage route handler, and then... nothing.  It doesn't hit either of the success or error handlers defined in the `Ember.$.get`

When I execute this code in development against a real web-server, it works fine.

Does Mirage support the `async:false` flag?
I also tried using `this.pretender.get` syntax to declare my end-point using the synchronous style defined here: https://github.com/pretenderjs/pretender#timing-parameter
But still no joy...

Any ideas, nudges in the right direction, etc. would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: If you do `async: true` does it work? Also, why is this request synchronous?

Comment: Yeah, it works fine with async: true.  It needs to be async because it's acting as an endpoint for a request that doesn't know, and can't be altered to know, about callbacks.  The magic of implementing conformance to a 2001 spec.

Comment: Next step would be to try a synchronous request against a "vanilla" Pretender server